# Cannot install WAS 8.5 Server Tools on Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, websphere, eclipse-luna

I am trying install WAS 8.5 Server Tools on Eclipse Luna but get the following error, any suggestion what can it be?

[image]

**UPDATE:** Immediately after I start the installation it shows the message:

> "Cannot perform operation. Computing alternate solutions, may take a
>   while: ..."

This is the detailed error message (thanks to [nitind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27905/nitind))

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.   Software currently installed: m2e - slf4j over logback logging (Optional) 1.5.2.20150413-2215 (org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature.feature.group 1.5.2.20150413-2215)   Missing requirement: m2e - slf4j over logback logging (Optional)
1.5.2.20150413-2215 (org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature.feature.group 1.5.2.20150413-2215) requires 'org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration [1.5.2.20150413-2215]' but it could not be found
```

Comment: Scroll down in the details pane and get all of the text.

Comment: @nitind, hi! I've updated my question, tnx for pointing me out that it isn't complete error message. It was hard to see.

Comment: Looks like it wants a version dated more closely to Mars. What steps are you following to do this install?